# How do I connect two horizontal Qsliders where their maximum and minimum values are dependent on each others current values for pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QSlider, QLabel, QListWidget
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
```

This are my parameters for my horizontal slider max and min values.

```
df_min = 0
df_max = 100

class Window(QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.title = 'urbs visualization'
    self.top = 300
    self.left = 500
    self.width = 800
    self.height = 600
    self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
    self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
    hbox = QHBoxLayout()
```

I am trying to create 2 horizontal sliders where if lets say t_start's value has been adjusted to 50. The new t_end minimum for its range will be t_start current value + 1
Likewise for t_start, when t_end's value becomes 70, I want t _start's new range to become 69(t_end - 1)
I have been able to achieve this with ipywidgets on jupyter notebook. As Qt designer is new to me, it is a difficult for me.

```
    #parameters for time widgets
    #time horizontal slider
    self.t_start = QSlider()
    self.t_start.setOrientation(Qt.Horizontal)
    self.t_end = QSlider()
    self.t_end.setOrientation(Qt.Horizontal)
    #t_start constraints
    self.t_start.setRange(df_min, df_max - 1)
    self.t_start.valueChanged.connect(self.changedValue)
    self.label = QLabel(str(df_min))
    self.label.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Sanserif', 15))
    
    #t_end constraints
    self.t_end.setRange(df_min + 1, df_max)
    self.t_end.setSliderPosition(df_max)
    self.t_end.valueChanged.connect(self.changedValue_2)
    
    #testing constraints
    self.t_start.valueChanged().t_end.setRange(t_start.value() + 1, df_max)
    #self.t_end.rangeChanged(self.t_start.value(), df_max)
    self.label_2 = QLabel(str(df_max))
    self.label_2.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Sanserif', 15))
    
    #adding widgets
    hbox.addWidget(self.t_start)
    hbox.addWidget(self.label)
    hbox.addWidget(self.t_end)
    hbox.addWidget(self.label_2)
    self.setLayout(hbox)
    self.show()

def changedValue(self):
    size = self.t_start.value()
    self.label.setText(str(size))
def changedValue_2(self):
    size_2 = self.t_end.value()
    self.label_2.setText(str(size_2))

App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Let me see if I get it straight: t_start has a range of 0-99, t_end 1-100, when you move t_start to 50 you want t_end's range to 51-100, and when you move t_end to 70 you want t_start to be 0-69, right?

Comment: yes you are right about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the range values of sliders using the result of the `valueChanged` signal (that there's no need to call `value()`), as it is the argument of the signal.

Note that QLabel has a convenience function to set numeric values: [`setNum()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#setNum).

```
    def changedValue(self, size):
        self.label.setNum(size)
        self.t_end.setMinimum(size + 1)

    def changedValue_2(self, size):
        self.label_2.setNum(size)
        self.t_start.setMaximum(size - 1)
```

Be aware that, even if it's not your case, reciprocal setting of properties like this (ranges of sliders or spinboxes) *could* lead to recursion.